# Is an OpenID identity always acceptable as an OpenID provider URL?

Tags: openid

Apologies if my terminology is inaccurate.

I have an application which acts as an OpenID relying party. Suppose a user signs up via OpenID, and provides me with the URL for his OpenID provider. The authentication happens, and I receive back an OpenID Identity.

If I need to authenticate the user again, can I always use the Identity, instead of the originally-supplied URL?

A concrete example, in case the above is nonsense. To use Google as their OpenID provider, the user enters `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`. Once authenticated, Google provides me with an Identity URL like `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=A1B2c3d45F6g7`. I can subsequently authenticate using that Identity URL (I've checked); but is that guaranteed true for all providers?

Answer (score 0):

That identity URL is the Claimed Identifier. The [spec says](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#identifying) that it "SHOULD be used by the Relying Party as a key for local storage of information about the user." So you can be fairly confident that for any correctly implemented provider that you'll get a stable Claimed Identifier for a given user.

Do note, however, that such an identifier is often particular to each RP's domain (well, technically, *realm*; this feature is a privacy safeguard to prevent RPs from colluding in tracking user activity across different services). So you might get different identifiers for the same user between e.g. your staging environment and your production environment.

Comment: Yes, I know the Claimed Identifier (thanks for the correct term!) is stable. I want to know if I can use it as the target of an OpenID request. Can I request authentication from `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=A1B2c3d45F6g7` instead of `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`?